# Creating formula to display group income in ascending order in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-formulas

Good morning everyone,
I'm trying to create a formula for a report I'm writing in Crystal that groups annual household incomes in increments of 10,000 in ascending order. So far I've followed what I'd believed to be the proper "if-then" pattern. But I'm getting an error that reads "The remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula."
Here is the code content:
`crAscendingOrder`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 10001 then "$0 to $10,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 20001.00 then "$10,001 to $20,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 30001.00 then "$20,001 to $30,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 40001.00 then "$30,001 to $40,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 50001.00 then "$40,001 to $50,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 60001.00 then "$50,001 to $60,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 70001.00 then "$60,001 to $70,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 80001.00 then "$70,001 to $80,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 90001.00 then "$80,001 to $90,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 100001.00 then "$90,001 to $100,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 110001.00 then "$100,001 to $110,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 120001.00 then "$110,001 to $120,000"`
`if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 130001.00 then "$130,000 and over"`

What happens is the error checker only highlights the last 12 lines of code. I'm a bit rusty so if anyone has any advice I'd very much appreciate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to inclue `else` after the strings

```
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 10001 then "$0 to $10,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 20001.00 then "$10,001 to $20,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 30001.00 then "$20,001 to $30,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 40001.00 then "$30,001 to $40,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 50001.00 then "$40,001 to $50,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 60001.00 then "$50,001 to $60,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 70001.00 then "$60,001 to $70,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 80001.00 then "$70,001 to $80,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 90001.00 then "$80,001 to $90,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 100001.00 then "$90,001 to $100,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 110001.00 then "$100,001 to $110,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 120001.00 then "$110,001 to $120,000" else
if{ss_client_data_set.income}< 130001.00 then "$130,000 and over"
```

You could also use a case statement to clean it up a bit:

```
Select {ss_client_data_set.income}
Case is < 10001: "$0 to $10,000"
Case is < 20001.00: $10,001 to $20,000"
etc...
etc...
default: "doesn't fall within range"
;
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, Justin. I added the "else" statements and afterward there was another problem, however, not to deflate your response. The error now reads "A string is required here" highlighting the "10001.00" before the "then" in the first line. I'd assume it'd be the same for the rest of those similar values. But I don't want it to be a string it considers. I need for it to be a numerical value. Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Is {ss_client_data_set.income} a numerical value in your database? I'm testing the formula on my end, and when I use a string as the value I get the same error. However, when I use an integer the formula works just fine. If it is in fact a string, try to convert it to a number using the ToNumber function. So...."if ToNumber({ss_client_data_set.income})<10001 then......"

Comment: Let me plug than in and give it a try. I don't think the guys who originally converted this data did a very good job. Kind of a tangent but if you were to look at it simply from an ascending order sort it would actually place higher values lower in some instances due to places along the basic numerical structure and then subordinating the decimal rules. It's just weird. I've not seen anything like it.

Comment: That sounds like they are string values. Gotta love cleaning up others' messes :)